# C++ Map with multiple types

Tags: c++, types, dictionary

I need to create a map with three types.

```
map<string,string,double>
```

How do I create it and use it?

Comment: You don't; well, not that way.  Can you explain what you want?  A map is an associative container: you have a key (type 1), and a value (type 2).  The types that comprise those two things are up to you, if you need to store more than a simple type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that you need to associate two pieces of data with one index, then you can use `std::pair`:

```
map<string, pair<string, double> > m;

m["greeting"] = pair<string, double>("hello", 3.2);
// or: m["greeting"] = make_pair("hello", 3.2);

cout << m["greeting"].first << endl; // prints hello
cout << m["greeting"].second << endl; // prints 3.2
```

Comment: A handy function is `make_pair("hello", 3.2)` which saves having to repeat the types.

Comment: @GregHewgill ah thanks, didn't know about that function. I added a note about it.